# How to set autoUpload option to Jquery File Upload

Tags: jquery, file, upload

i'm trying to set autoUpload flag to [jQuery File Upload](https://github.com/blueimp/jQuery-File-Upload).
So i try editing `jquery.fileupload.js` in this way:

```
(function (factory) {
    'use strict';
    if (typeof define === 'function' && define.amd) {
        // Register as an anonymous AMD module:
        define([
            'jquery',
            'jquery.ui.widget'
        ], factory);
    } else {
        // Browser globals:
        factory(window.jQuery);
    }
}(function ($) {
    'use strict';

    // The FileReader API is not actually used, but works as feature detection,
    // as e.g. Safari supports XHR file uploads via the FormData API,
    // but not non-multipart XHR file uploads:
    $.support.xhrFileUpload = !!(window.XMLHttpRequestUpload && window.FileReader);
    $.support.xhrFormDataFileUpload = !!window.FormData;

    // The fileupload widget listens for change events on file input fields defined
    // via fileInput setting and paste or drop events of the given dropZone.
    // In addition to the default jQuery Widget methods, the fileupload widget
    // exposes the "add" and "send" methods, to add or directly send files using
    // the fileupload API.
    // By default, files added via file input selection, paste, drag & drop or
    // "add" method are uploaded immediately, but it is possible to override
    // the "add" callback option to queue file uploads.
    $.widget('blueimp.fileupload', {

        options: {
            // The namespace used for event handler binding on the dropZone and
            // fileInput collections.           
            // If not set, the name of the widget ("fileupload") is used.
            namespace: undefined,
            autoUpload:true,
            .
            .
            .
```

and `main.js` in this way:

```
$(function () {
    'use strict';

    // Initialize the jQuery File Upload widget:
    $('#fileupload').fileupload();

    // Enable iframe cross-domain access via redirect option:
    $('#fileupload').fileupload(
        'option',
        'redirect',
        window.location.href.replace(
            /\/[^\/]*$/,
            '/cors/result.html?%s'
        )
    );

    if (window.location.hostname === 'blueimp.github.com') {
        // Demo settings:
        $('#fileupload').fileupload('option', {
            url: '//jquery-file-upload.appspot.com/',
            maxFileSize: 5000000,
            autoUpload:true,
            .
            .
            .
```

i can see through this

```
<td class="start">{% if (!o.options.autoUpload) { %}
    <button class="btn btn-primary">
        <i class="icon-upload icon-white"></i>
        <span>{%=locale.fileupload.start%}</span>
    </button>
{% } %}</td>
```

that start button appears, so o.options.autoUpload is `false`, but i set it to `true`.
What can i do? in which way i can set autoupload to upload image directly when it is selected?
thanks!!!!

Answer (score 15, accepted):

i solved taking the original example downloaded from the plugin site and i change flag `autoUpload:true` and it works :)

Comment: Thanks Jack.  Your answer really helped me out.  I simply added $('#fileupload').fileupload('option', { autoUpload:true }); to main.js and it worked.  Be careful not to put it within the if (window.location.hostname === 'blueimp.github.com') block.

Comment: This won't work for me at all.  The autoUpload option only appears in `jquery.fileupload-ui.js`, so I changed it to `true` with no success.  I also tried clone45's method and that didn't work either.  Any ideas?

Comment: I found my own solution.  On the page where you drop the uploads, I added a `setInterval` that checks every half a second to see if a 'Start' button exists and clicks it. So far it seems to work great.

Comment: Thanks, its worked fine with Rails 4, just i have added "$('#fileupload').fileupload('option', { autoUpload:true});"